# Extend build.gradle

Tags: gradle, inheritance, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to add some extra properties to a `build.gradle` I can't change because it is symlinked to another repo which I can't change. I also can't change `gradle.properties`.

I want to add these properties to build.gradle:

```
ext {
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.3.1'
    grpcVersion = '1.41.0'
    protobufVersion = '3.17.3'
}
```

Is there a way to make a `build.gradle` of your own and import the `build.gradle` I can't modify into it, then add these extra properties to it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, in your `build-override.gradle` you have as below

```
ext {
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.3.1'
    grpcVersion = '1.41.0'
    protobufVersion = '3.17.3'
}

apply from: ./build.gradle //orig build gradle
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't put a plugins block after this code, so it doesn't seem complete...? How can I inherit a build.gradle and choose my plugins afterwards?

Comment: you can split the common gradle - moving the plugins and rest of the functions into different files. i.e. multiple files for common parts - modularity needs some compromise